# How do you obtain the sum in base 5 notation:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here my question :Perform the following arithmetic operations for the numbers in the bases indicated and write out answers in base 5 notation:
a)  244 + 132 (base 5).
b)  11101 × 111 (base 2). 
c)  F7 – B6 (base 16).
 this is the first time I hear of(Base 5 notation)
can anyone help please ?

Comment: It seems you are a new user to the site.  I encourage you to complete the tutorial at http://math.stackexchange.com/tour, and also to check which answer (if any) below you accept.  Welcome to MSE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of different number bases like a variation of the base 10 decimal system we already use.  I'll explain by working out the first problem you list and then leave the others to you.

In base 5, you would count starting at zero and have the following numbers:

$$\{0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14,20,21,\dots\}.$$

In this system, the 'ones column' tells how many ones, or multiples of $5^0$ you have, the next column to the left of a number is not the tens place, but the fives, so it tells what multiple of $5^1$ you have.  So for example, $14_5$ is $9_{10}$, meaning 14 in base 5 is the same as 9 in base 10 because you have 1 $5^1$ and 4 ones.

With this in mind, you can carry and borrow with addition and subtraction as usual, so

$$244_5+132_5=3(5^2)+7(5^1)+6(5^0).$$

Now we need to carry any multiple that is 5 or more to the column to the left, so we rewrite this expression as

$$3(5^2)+8(5^1)+1(5^0)=4(5^2)=3(5^1)+1(5^0)=431_5.$$

Answer (score 0):

It’s valuable to have a little experience and skill in such computations. The idea is to think carefully of what you’re doing when you do decimal computations with paper and pencil, then carry the principles over to the unfamiliar situation.

To add $244_5$ and $132_5$, you start with the units digit, and add $4+2=6_{10}=11_5$. So your units digit is $1$, with a carry of $1$ to the next column. Now you’re adding $4+3+1=8_{10}=13_5$, so the second place gets a $3$, with a carry of $1$ again to the next column. And so it goes.

If you want to do multiplication, you should prepare yourself with a $5\times5$ multiplication table of numbers written in base $5$: for instance $3\times4=12_{10}=22_5$. Again the procedure is the same as in the familiar situation, but you just have to be careful and think of what you’re doing.